# Best way of SolidWorks rendering for product catalogs

Tags: design, cad, solidworks, machine-elements

For a catalog of many different parts I want a clear render but not as 'realistic' or detailed as I would get with SW Visualize. Are there any other options or settigns to achieve this?

Some examples:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Sounds like you want to render in visualise, render outlines ("cartoon"), and then overlay them?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift thanks, that might work. Would I then get a cartoon like image or still more a bit realistic like?

Comment: I personally find screenshots of the work area (shaded + edges) to have the right amount of detail for most purposes.

Comment: Save as .PNG of the work area allows you to export in higher resolution, too. Make sure you turn up image quality before export - I have a macro just for this!